# el-get in Emacs "No Match"?

Tags: emacs

Demonstrating this problem on 20.04:

```
sudo apt install el-get
```

Run emacs, hit <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> and type `el-get-install`

Get "No Match".

Attempt to solve it:

Run `dpkg -l` on `el-get` and observe that there is a start script in `/etc/emacs/site-start.d/50el-get.el`, which suggests that there is a global configuration that allows emacs to run `el-get` start scripts.

So why is the script not loaded ("No Match")?

---

Update:

I switched to [melph](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MELPA) and installed the desired package that way.

Comment: Was the script there when `emacs` started?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) (see https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/el-get )

Comment: There was no .emacsrc and this error can be observed from freshly created new user account which shouldn't have any custom scripts